# How to connect a Windows CE peripheral to my Macbook?

Tags: windows, mojave, mount, driver

I am trying to connect a device on Windows CE on my Macbook.

The device is a *in-situ* gamma spectrometer running on Windows CE. The files that I need to retrieve are the .cnf files containing the measurment results. On a Windows PC, connecting this equipment necessitate the windows mobile device center.

For now, when I try to connect it to my Macbook Pro (Mojave 10.14.4), nothing happens and I can't see any mounted peripheral. I have tried to use SyncMate software, without any result.
For workflow optimization reasons, I do not want to have to use a virtual machine with windows on it.

Is there a way to retrieve my data from this peripheral on my mac ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: After a quick [web search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931937/description-of-windows-mobile-device-center), I find that `windows mobile device center` requires Microsoft Vista. Is this correct or did I miss something?

Comment: My question is whether it is possible to do without the Windows operating system and the windows mobile device center

Comment: That's a tough one, I couldn't find anything that did that directly but there seems to be a beta dropbox client for WinCE that might help transfer files. Its OLD but that was only the first one I found. https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/droppedboxx-unofficial-dropbox-client-windows-mobile/

Comment: Unfortunately (i) my gamma spectrometer run a modified version of Windows CE (ii) I won't risk to install something "found on the web" on a 20k€ machine. I am thinking about a solution on the Mac OS side...